# Jekyll Markdown html entity

Tags: jekyll, html-entities, kramdown

I have a Jekyll website and I ofter use markdown (with kramdown) syntax for the posts.
I want that if I write in a .md file:

```
Lui esaminò la città e la trovò molto bella mentre ora è uno schifo
```

The result html will be:

```
Lui esamin&ograve; la citt&agrave; e la trov&ograve; molto bella mentre ora &egrave; uno schifo
```

Now it doesn't put the html entity, better it changes only lsquo rsquo ldquo and rdquo
How can achieve this results?

Answer (score 0):

I would use utf-8 encoding in the HTML to prevent this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue at the very beginning when dealing with Chinese characters.

You may need to add `<meta charset="utf-8">` in `<head>...</head>` part of your template layout, and then html will display correctly in the browser.